# Local web application as a captive portal with out authentication?

Tags: local-area-network, node.js, web-applications, captive-portal

We are in the final stages of developing an in-browser mobile app which will run in a non Internet-connected environment (on a submarine).

We are running a server inside the submarine (Windows 8 laptop with node.js), and the app runs in node.js.

There is a wireless router through which the server and clients connect, with the server being assigned a reserved static IP address by the DHCP server. All other connections are handled by the same DHCP, with in an IP range.

Right now we can access the app from mobile devices through the browser by typing in the IP address of the server, but what we want to accomplish is to have a captive portal, where every time a device is connected to the wireless network, the browser will automatically load our app. We don't want users to have to type an IP address on their browsers.

We have a Linksys router with CoovaAp firmware installed but are not sure how to proceed.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this would be of help: [walkthrough on how to setup public hotspot with coovaap](http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/walkthrough-how-to-setup-a-public-hotspot-with-coovaap.69495/)

I don't know much about Linksys with CoovaAp, but basically, with CoovaChilli you would redirect via **uamserver**, **uamhomepage**.
I hope this would get you closer to what you want to achieve, if you have not done it already.

Cheers.